# Celery task .delay method is not asynchronous

Tags: python, celery, pytest

I am trying to test task in pytest test suite by running .delay command on it:

```
def test_selected_rows_are_blocked(celery_worker):
    id, select_only = 0, ['a', 'b']
    tasks.update_table.delay(id, select_only)
    
    # some code here that should be called as soon as task gets started
```

So, the task can run, but the code that goes after it runs synchronously.
`celery_worker` fixture uses my own celery app for tests and `task_always_eager=True` is set, which is not recommended, however, otherwise task does not execute code inside it, I simply checked it by raising error from the task.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve in your test and why it needs to be asynchronous.

Comment: @lain Shelvington The task must lock a table row for update, ```with_select_for_update( )``` from SQLAlchemy and than update row and commit it, it takes around 5 seconds before ```session.commit( )``` gets called. So, meanwhile I want to check that the lock works properly by trying to update the same row, so this part goes after the task gets called. Hope this helps.

Comment: `task_always_eager=True` this always run task synchronously, you can set it to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation about [task_always_eager](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_always_eager) again...

Let me quote (and bold) the crucial part:

> If this is True, all tasks will be executed locally by **blocking** until the task returns. apply_async() and Task.delay() will return an EagerResult instance, that emulates the API and behavior of AsyncResult, except the result is already evaluated.

In other words, tasks are executed more/less like regular functions on your local machine.